# WPF Combined Geometry Scales View

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

i'm trying to model an old scale in WPF. Therefore i need to add an ellipse and a rectangle and all i need is the cutting volume.
I tried Combined Geometry:

```
<Grid>

    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Path.Data>


            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Intersect">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="50,50" />
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding ElementName=recForm, Path=RenderedGeometry}"  >
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Rectangle x:Name="recForm" Visibility="Hidden" Fill="#000000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="25,-11,25,11">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>


</Grid>
```

But I can't see anything. Any Ideas?

Comment: Look at the Debug output; the binding is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't debug it. I fixed it :)

Comment: Changed it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. My Code looks like:

```
    <Path>
        <Path.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF252525" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF474747" Offset="0.965"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA6A5A5" Offset="0.829"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="50,51" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" ></EllipseGeometry>

        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Clip>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Intersect">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="50,51" />
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,0,50,50">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform CenterX="85" CenterY="-15" Angle="45"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Clip>
    </Path>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="ScaleBody" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="100" Height="100" >
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="scaleBodyTransform" Angle="-24"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Label Content="-9" FontSize="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="41" Canvas.Top="1"  />
            <Label Content="5" FontSize="10" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-24.505"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="4" FontSize="10" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="13" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-47.684"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="3" FontSize="10" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="26" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-72.35"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label  Content="2" FontSize="10" Canvas.Left="4" Canvas.Top="42" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-97.669"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="1" FontSize="10" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="58" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-120.409"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="0" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="216.695"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-1" Canvas.Left="34" Canvas.Top="77" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-167.488"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-2" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="77" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="169.538"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-3" Canvas.Left="64" Canvas.Top="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="144.36"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-4" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="56" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="120.457"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-5" Canvas.Left="79" Canvas.Top="41" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="96.966"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-6" Canvas.Left="77" Canvas.Top="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="71.036"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-7" Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="48.161"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="10" Content="-8" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="24.467"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas.Clip>

            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Intersect">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="50,51" />
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,0,50,50">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform CenterX="85" CenterY="-15" Angle="45"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>

        </Canvas.Clip>

    </Canvas>
    <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="25.5,-17,24.5,17">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="3" Height="5" Margin="49,2,48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>

    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>


            <CombinedGeometry x:Name="Scale" GeometryCombineMode="Intersect">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="50,51" />
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,0,50,50">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform CenterX="85" CenterY="-15" Angle="45"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Label x:Name="lblFillBalance" Content="00:00" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="9"/>
```

The Output looks like:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIxCp.png)

The only thing wont work is setting the locking the angle of the Canvas.Clip to the angle of Canvas

**EDIT**

Everything works fine now. For everyone whos intreseted, i edited the XAML code above and here is my methode to spin the wheel.

```
     private int setScaleBodyToBalance()
    {
        int balance = Program.TodayPresence.balanceWhenLeave();

        int angle = 0;
        if (balance >= 0) angle = 144 - balance / 150;
        if (balance >= -5400 && balance < 0 ) angle = 144 + Math.Abs(balance) / 150;
        if (balance < -5400) angle = -180 + (Math.Abs(balance) - 5400  )/ 150;       

        return angle;

    }

    public void updateShownInformation()
    {
        scaleBodyTransform.Angle = setScaleBodyToBalance();
    }
```

Balance is an integer which gives us a time. When Balance is 3600 the time is 1:00 ...